# How can I disable the Refresh button and keyboard shortcuts in Firefox, while leaving the context menu entry active?

Tags: firefox

I have to type something here to meet requirements. How can I disable the Refresh button and keyboard shortcuts in Firefox, while leaving the context menu entry active? I want to prevent [m]any accidental refreshes.

The only idea I had was to use a hot-key program, but I'm curious to know how to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the F5 button, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482059/disable-f5-and-browser-refresh-using-javascript).
Keep in mind this answer is here in case you are developing the site:
I'll copy the code here for accessibility:

```
// slight update to account for browsers not supporting e.which
function disableF5(e) { if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116) e.preventDefault(); };
// To disable f5
$(document).bind("keydown", disableF5);
OR
$(document).on("keydown", disableF5);
// To re-enable f5
$(document).unbind("keydown", disableF5);
OR
$(document).off("keydown", disableF5);
```

Otherwise, you can check in the Firefox options, under Hotkeys.